# View a PDF from SSRS / RDL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I want to access an RDL to obtain the report as PDF.  I have

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string pdfOutputFIleName = @"C:\Development\testoutputAsPdf.pdf";
        var urlAsPdf = @"http://serverName/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ExecutionID=xxx&Culture=1033&CultureOverrides=False&UICulture=9&UICultureOverrides=False&ReportStack=1&ControlID=yyy&OpType=Export&FileName=Bug+Status&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=PDF";

        var client = new WebClient();
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        //client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

        Process(client, urlAsPdf, pdfOutputFIleName);

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void Process(WebClient client, string url, string outputFileName)
    {
        Stream data = client.OpenRead(url);
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
        {
            string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
            using (Stream s = File.Create(outputFileName))
            {
                var writer = new StreamWriter(s);
                writer.Write(output);
                Console.WriteLine(output);                                        
            }
        }
    }
```

The URL works fine in my browser.  The program runs.  When I to open the PDF I receive an error in Adobe:

> There was an error opening this document.  The file is damaged and
>   could not be repaired.

Comment: Not sure if related, but shouldn't you close the `StreamWriter` at some point?

Comment: Did you try to use the web service provided by Reporting Services?

Comment: Due to the application requirements, web services are not an option.  The HTML rendering works fine so I suspect its something particular to the PDF.  @PoweredByOrange, yes true I should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already specify the output file name and the url to read from, perhaps you can use the `WebClient.DownloadFile(string address, string filename)` member.

```
private static void Process(WebClient client, string url, string outputFileName)
{
    client.DownloadFile(url, outputFileName);
}
```